# What is the error in this Solidity code? it compiles but errors on runtime

Tags: python, runtime-error, ethereum, solidity

Here is the function. It's a part of a larger contract, which runs perfectly with no error.

```
address payable public coldStorage;
event toColdStorage (address from, uint256 amount, uint toBlockchain, string toAddress);
event removedFromColdStorage (address to, uint256 amount, uint fromBlockchain, string fromAddress);

function getFromStorage(address payable _to, uint _fromBlockchain, string memory _fromAddress) public payable {
    require(msg.sender == coldStorage, "Only the owners can call this function");
    _to.transfer(msg.value);
    emit removedFromColdStorage(_to, msg.value, _fromBlockchain, _fromAddress);
  }
```

When I call this function (using Python3), and only this function, the contract doesn't complete the transaction and I get this error

```
raise ContractLogicError(f'execution reverted: {response["error"]["message"]}')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

I am calling the function like so,

```
contract.functions.getFromStorage(w3.eth.accounts[2], 2, '9WzDXwBbmkg8ZTbNMqUxvQRAyrZzDsGYdLVL9zYtAWWM').transact({'value':500000000000000000})
```

But I don't think the error is here since the same format works for other functions in this contract.

From the error, it looks like I made a logical error, but I can't figure out the location of the error.

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

To me, the address you are providing doesn't look like an Ethereum address (a quick google search suggests it's a Solana address). Have you tried using a different address for `_to`?

Comment: So ```_to``` is coming from the inbuilt ETH addresses, as referenced by ```w3.eth.accounts[2]```. The _fromAddress is suppose to be a SOL address.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. Have you made sure that you are calling the function as the owner?